# Help with this randomization distribution in R in this exercise

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

This question is from this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119163668), page 313

Suppose we are interested in the proportion of flights arriving more than 30 minutes after the scheduled time. Of the $1,000$ Delta flights, $67$ arrived more than $30$ minutes late, and of the $1,000$ United flights, 160 arrived more than 30 minutes late. We are testing to see if this provides evidence to conclude that the proportion of flights that are over 30 minutes late is different between flying United or Delta.

I want to find the p-value if the null hypothesis is $p_u=p_d$ and the alternative hypothesis is $p_u\neq p_d$, where $p_u$ and $p_d$ are the proportions of the late flights from united and Delta respectively.

My solution in R:

```
s = c(rep(1,67), rep(2,67), rep(0,2000-67-67))
x=0
for(i in 1:5000)
{
y = sample(s,2000, replace = T)
x=append(x, (sum(y==1)/1000)-(sum(y==2)/1000))
}
pvalue = sum(x>=0.093)/length(x) + sum(x<=-0.093)/length(x)
```

In order to make the randomization distribution I mixed everything together with the same proportion $67/1000$. In the end I had a sample with $2000$ flights with $67$ late flights from united and $67$ from Delta. I used the numbers 1 and 2 to represented these flights (1 to united and 2 to Delta or vice versa). Am I doing right?

Comment: There's no way this can be correct because it doesn't include the 160 datum anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what exactly you are doing or why. But if all you want is to test whether the two proportions are similar, then a proportion test will do the job.

```
> prop.test(c(67,160),c(1000,1000))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(67, 160) out of c(1000, 1000)
X-squared = 42.06, df = 1, p-value = 8.851e-11
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.12150319 -0.06449681
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
 0.067  0.160
```